# selenium selector - how to check checkboxes?

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

I don't seem to be able to use click for checkboxes.
No error in the console, it shows the click but the checkbox isn't checked.
I have tried using both `click` and `check` but neither seem to check the checkbox.
Using the database id (102) as suggested by the IDE recorder is not an option as the ID's change with each run.

I am trying: `css=fieldset.choices ol li label input` for my locator.

I also tried: `//fieldset[@class='choices']//ol//li//label//input` and again the console says clicked but the checkbox doesn't actually get checked in the browser.

I also tried: `//input[@type='checkbox']` for the selector as it is the first checlbox on the screen but no luck with that, but no explicit error.

The HTML is:

```html
<fieldset class="choices">
  <legend class="label">
    <label>
      Grades
    </label>
  </legend>
  <input id="school_grades_none" type="hidden" value="" name="school[grade_ids][]">
  </input>
  <ol class="choices-group">
    <li class="choice">
      <label for="school_grade_ids_102">
        <input id="school_grade_ids_102" type="checkbox" value="102" style="border: none" name="school[grade_ids][]">
        </input>
        PK3
      </label>
    </li>
    <li class="choice">
    ...
    </li>
    <li class="choice"></li>
    ...
    </li>
    <li class="choice"></li>
    ...
    </li>
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about when you use `id=school_grade_ids_102` as your locator, instead of the xpath or css.

**UPDATE**

How about you use `contains` like so

```
//input[contains(@id, 'school_grade_ids_')] # add [1] or [2], etc. at the end
```

Comment: Might be useful.  I guess I would put a [1], [2], etc. after it to go after each checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
setCheckboxValue(By.id("checkboxId"), true /* or false*/);

public void setCheckboxValue(By by, boolean checked) {
        WebElement e = getDriver().findElement(by);
        if(!e.isSelected() && checked) {
            e.click();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but not using Java/C just using the IDE, where would I put this in the IDE?