# how to check checkbox in Selenium with java?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I want check a checkbox in Selenium WebDriver with java , but It returns an exception  ElementNotVisibleException.Element is currently not visible ...

The element is invisible but not hidden. I tried it  with both firefox and PhantomJS but it doesn't work.

I found many suggestions here  but it still not work

HTML code :

```
<span class="checkbox"> 
<input id="terms-checkbox" class="required" type="checkbox" name="terms_agreement">
</input> 
<label for="terms-checkbox"></label>
</span>
```

Comment: Add some more details: HTML, what have you tried, and so on. Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16651610/selenium-selector-how-to-check-checkboxes

Comment: I tried to test a website with selenium in a maven project. So , the test works finely but not to check the chekbox ,  I can see the element in the browser with firefox or PhantomJS. but it can't check it and I got an excpetion . I think it's a visibilty issues but I don't know the solution

Comment: for (int second = 0;; second++) {
     if (second >= 60) fail("timeout");
     try { if (isElementPresent(By.id("terms-checkbox"))) break; } catch (Exception e) {}
     Thread.sleep(1000);
    }

  driver.findElement(By.id("terms-checkbox")).click();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in question, the element is not hidden but could not find. So, it may be visible through label tag. You should try with the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for='terms-checkbox']")).click();
```